# What major sites are using the HTML5 nav element?

Tags: html, nav

There's an ongoing debate of the best use of the new `<nav>` tag in HTML5.  I am researching the use of the `<nav>` element in the wild, and while I've found some sites using HTML5, I am curious to see if any major site is using it. By major I mean household name.  If you could point any out it will be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove the CSS tag and the last paragraph IMO. It's not relevant; this is not a CSS question in *any* sense.

Comment: @meagar my thinking was that the users who care a lot about css would have an interest on this, but you are right, its mistagged. i was thinking of just deleting the question.  is this not the right sort of question for SO?

Comment: The question is fine for SO, and I've fixed the tag. Carry on! :)

Comment: @Sebastian I consider it fairly on-topic within the HTML5 tag; The vote-to-close wasn't me.

Comment: @meagar, @Toji: i'm still a bit of a noob on SO etiquette.  If i get no replies by tomorrow, should i just delete the question?

Comment: @Sebastian There's no reason to delete your question; people searching for similar problems may come up with new solutions in the future.

Comment: @Sebastian If you have no answers after 24 hours, try editing the question body by adding new information. Editing the question will bring the question back to SO front-page...

Comment: on a related note, it would be nice if anyone could recommend a firefox add-in that alerts you when the site you are browsing is using HTML5 markup.

Comment: @darasd: i'm using the web developer toolbar "oultine custom elements" option to hunt for HTML5 tags on a page. not ideal, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website of the Chilean President was one of the first mainstream sites to use HTML5, including nav, section, aside, etc. elements:
http://www.gobiernodechile.cl/

As for an addon to show indicate sites using HTML5, I made an extension for Opera here:
https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/html5-powered/

and a UserJS version which should work in Firefox using GreaseMonkey:
http://people.opera.com/danield/extensions/HTML5Powered.user.js

Other mainstream websites now using HTML5:

- http://www.oprah.com/
- http://www.economist.com/
- http://www.barackobama.com/
- http://jerryseinfeld.com/

Comment: wow, very thorough, thank you tagawa. where is wikipedia using html5? specifically the nav element?

Comment: Oh, I can't find a Wikipedia page using HTML5 now. I've removed it from the list until I can remember where I saw it, but they do have an HTML5 template: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Www.wikipedia.org_template/html5

Answer (score 2):

not really a site, but a [page](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html) within apple's site

Comment: +1 good catch darasd!  i;ll keep the question open for a bit, to see if i can compile a list.